# SWIFT // Nested arrays of structures

Tags: swift

I can't figure it out in any way.
I have two structures

```
struct Meal {
    var name: String
    var food: [Food]
}

struct Food {
    var name: String
    var description: String
}
```

And when I declare the instance it looks like this

```
var meal = [
    Meal(name: "Breakfast", food: [Food(name: "Omlet", description: "Two eggs")]),
    Meal(name: "Dinner", food: [
        Food(name: "Potato", description: "Three potatos"),
        Food(name: "Salad", description: "Сucumbers and cabbage")
        ])
    ]
```

But no matter how hard I try I just can't get a direct access to values in Food structure. How should I properly do it?

Comment: You need to iterate over the `food` property since it's an array using a `for` loop or similar or access it using a subscript like `food[0]` but be careful so you don't use an index that doesn't exists. You can read about arrays in the [Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html#ID107) book.

Comment: Try this `print(meal.first?.food.first?.name)`.

Comment: A meal's `food` property is an array, containing some number of Food objects. Which Food object did you want? Please show your real code where you try to "get a direct access to values in Food structure" so that we can understand your intentions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to @MuhtasimUlfatTanmoy

In order to get access to "Salad", for instance, I need to use following code

```
meal[1].food[1].name
```

For someone else who stuck on "Lab—Meal Tracker" in Apple "Develop in SWIFT Data Collection" book. Below the final code that works.

```
class FoodTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    var meals: [Meal] {
        return [
            Meal(name: "Breakfast", food: [
                Food(name: "Egs", description: "Two egs")
                ]),
            Meal(name: "Lunch", food: [
                Food(name: "Potato", description: "Three potatos"),
                Food(name: "Juice", description: "Lemonade")
                ]),
            Meal(name: "Dinner", food: [
                Food(name: "Salad", description: "Three Cucambers")
                ])
        ]
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return meals.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return meals[section].food.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Food", for: indexPath)
        let meal = meals[indexPath.section]
        let food = meal.food[indexPath.row]
        
        var content = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
        content.text = food.name
        content.secondaryText = food.description
        cell.contentConfiguration = content
        
        return cell
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return meals[section].name
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is a useful answer for anyone else since it is only usable for your hard coded case and might lead to a crash if applied to an arbitrary array.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson It just shows a general principle of how you could access the data in nested structures. If I had troubles with it, there is a chance that some else is also. In real code you would use counters or something that works for you.

meal[counterOne].food[counterTwo].name

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, added code of "Lab—Meal Tracker" in Apple "Develop in SWIFT Data Collection" book that this question is based on. Might be helpful to someone